# Typescript function overload makes arguments type of any

Tags: typescript

I've been trying to overload function but typescript, for some reason, highlights my function arguments with `any` type.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

I declared 2 types for objects:

`type SomeObj = {
  prop: number
}`

and

`type AnotherObj = {
  anotherProp: string
}`

and my function:

`interface SomeFunc {
  <T = AnotherObj>(a: T, b: true): T & SomeObj;
  <T = AnotherObj>(a: T, b?: boolean): T;
}`

Here is implementation section:

```
let someObj: SomeObj = {
  prop: 42
}

let someFunc: SomeFunc = function(a, b) {
  if (b === true) return Object.assign({}, a, someObj);
  else return a
}


var x = someFunc({ anotherProp: '1' }, true)
var y = someFunc({ anotherProp: '1' })
```

This function returns merged objects (`AnotherObj & SomeObj`) if second argument is true. Otherwise it returns first argument `AnotherObj`.

Even though I've got the right highlights when I check `x` and `y` results, TS still gives me a warning that function arguments are `implicitly any`. But it's clear that first argument is typeof `AnotherObj` and second is typeof `boolean | undefined`.

What should be changed in function interface declarations to eliminate this warning?
Here is link to [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=26&ssc=39&pln=15&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgeQEYCsoF4oG8CwAUFFGAE5xgBcUAdgK4KoRlEC%20RRokUAgrXGAALFmkw4CxKAEMBwlgAUK1KAGdgZAJa0A5u06FtwFgDNpAY2jwkAMXq1zeIiQA8AFWx85IsmIB8ABTSNG4ANFCoNBr0EACUIVAAZLCIKBgA3M5Q7p78gj7%20QSHhqAD8NKhwcAA2ELLxUG6ZhByEBrXAaqliNNZp4k5S5JQ0ACwATPpthB1dtvbmval2Dp4mC8CacLRBJbGDJJomUAGo2Fg40XFQZBDA9GS0UGIQ5sAAdNKqqpo6O7hscLScKqboYWLNEgQaqqaC3e6PGRTAwAN2kZCgAA9PKD5g4ArgZN5FMoaAByACMZKggKgV1iRDRGJAOOWCwJRPyJJGUEp1LYsSAA)

Answer (score 0):

In order to not repeat the types from the original interface I propose to use utility type `Parameters`.

```
let someFunc: SomeFunc = function(...[a,b]: Parameters<SomeFunc>) {
  if (b === true) return Object.assign({}, a, someObj);
  else return a
}
```

The main part is `...[a,b]: Parameters<SomeFunc>` we are saying that `a and b` arguments are of the type of arguments interface is defining. Pay attention that `a` will be always `unknown` inside the function, as its generically typed in `SomeFunc`.

Answer (score 0):

`let someFunc: SomeFunc` expects a `SomeFunc` function, since you are assigning an anonymous function you have to assure your anonymous function has the correct type:

```
let someFunc: SomeFunc = function<T>(a: T, b?: boolean) {
  if (b === true) return Object.assign({}, a, someObj);
  else return a
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=19&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=4#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgeQEYCsoF4oG8CwAUFFGAE5xgBcUAdgK4KoRlEC%20RRokUAgrXGAALFmkw4CxKAEMBwlgAUK1KAGdgZAJa0A5u06FtwFgDNpAY2jwkAMXq1zeIiQA8AFWx85IsmIB8ABTSNG4ANFCoNBr0EACUIVAAZLCIKBgA3M5Q7p78gj7%20QSHhqAD8NKhwcAA2ELLxUG6ZhByEBrXAaqliNNZp4k5S5JQ0ACwATPpthB1dtvbmval2Dp4mC8CacLTugcGNJeURVbX1gySaJlABqNhYONFxUGQQwPRktFBiEObAAHTSVSqTQ6WgBXBscLScKqboYWLNEgQaqqaAvN4fGRTAwAN2kZCgAA9PLD5g5wTJvIplDQAOQARlpUEhUEesSIeIJIBJywWFNk%20WpIygDKZbFiQA)

I not quite understand how are you using this in your live code but I would declare it in another way